# Installing WAP 2 for student access with Wireless laptops

Tags: windows-server-2003, wifi, access-point

I want students that have domain user accounts to be able to bring their laptops to school.  I have setup a radius IAS and created a self signed cert.  I have chosen to allow domain users to have access.  Does this mean that the student laptops must be part of the domain?  Or am I missing something.

Answer (score 1):

No, the laptops don't have to be part of the domain.  The credential will be supplied when they try to access the service (WAP).  If you have it tied into LDAP or AD, then they supply their domain credentials, and will be given access to the resource.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS.